# Binding a dynamically created html to the scope model

Tags: angularjs

Got stuck with something….

- I have a popover element for which I need to specify content.
- The content can be a String representing a HTML or a function that
  generates that HTML.
- The HTML of the popover should be a list of checkboxes that represent objects in an array that is part of the directive scope. The HTML is being requested every time I display the
  popover.
- Clicking those checkboxes should change the state of the objects in the array. What I stuck with is being able to consistently bind the newly generated HTML with the model on the scope.
- What I mean by that is that it might work the first time, but not any subsequent times, or might produce weird HTML to begin with.

What I did try and did work:

(a) Just putting this on a page obviously works (Meaning it is displayed
   correctly and clicking checkboxes does change the state of the
   objects)

```
<form id="{{id}}">
     <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="field in metadata.fields"> 
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.displayByDefault"> {{field.text}}
     </label>
</form>
```

(b) Grabbing form element as jQuery object ($(‘#FormId’)) and supplying that as an the content into popover options actually works, but only the first time, since it removes it from the DOM on the first use

(c) Taking that HTML and running through $compile in different ways either has no effect or produces a weird HTML (like producing n^2 number of checkboxes where n is the original number of checkboxes I should have)

Any suggestion would help.

**==== Update**

I have a hidden form that is when not hidden displays a functional html (that is checkboxes are updating the scope as needed). If I use the form itself and put it into the popover - it works only the first time. So At this point I am just trying to create a clone of that, bind to the scope and put it into the popover.

```
<form id="{{id}}_columnSelection">
    <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="field in metadata.fields"> <input type="checkbox"
        ng-model="field.displayByDefault"> {{field.text}}
    </label>
</form>
```

I am using the tipsy plugin to display a popover, so here is the JS that triggers the popover and the code that generates the html:

```
var getContent = function() {
    var $content = $('#' + $scope.configuration.id + '_columnSelection');
    var $clone = $content.clone(true, true);
    $compile($clone.contents())($scope);
    return $clone;
};

$columnSelector.popover({
 html : true,
 placement : 'left',
 trigger : 'manual',
 title : 'Select Columns',
 content : getContent()
});
$columnSelector.popover('toggle');
```

Comment: You need to use `$compile` to link the HTML with the scope. Can you post the code you were using to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might not help some, but here is the solution that worked in my particular case. The help comes from the fact that I am using tipsy plugin to display popover. And so I am using the plugin API to solve the problem rather than AngularJS.
Tipsy allows to specify content in couple of ways. One of them is 'content' option, and another one is 'template' option. If you use the template option, then you can reuse the html created on the page (no need to dynamically create it specifically for a popover) AND it is not destroyed on popover close. So in this case it just becomes a "regular AngularJs business as usual".